# Найти сумму простых делителей последовательности чисел

Tags: c++

Задание такое: надо найти сумму простых делителей последовательности чисел, одно из них 0; Простые делители - это те числа, которые делят число без остатка. К примеру у числа 6 делители.
1 2 3 и само число 6. Надо сделать обязательно через функцию. Проблема с алгоритмом, для одного числа описал функцию, а вот когда для нескольких считает белеберду.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int summa(int del, int elem, int s, int n)
{
    int sum;
    sum = 1;
    {
        if (elem != 0) {
            while (del <= elem) { 
                del = del + 1;
                if (fmod(elem, del) == 0)
                    sum = sum + del;
                else
                    n = 0;
                cout<<"\nS="<<sum;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int N = 1;
    int A[N]={0};   
    int i, p, a, s, nn;
    p=1; s=1;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout<<"VVedite "<<i<<" element:   "; 
        cin>>A[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        summa(p,A[i],s,nn);
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Comment: Обожаю такие `write once, read never` штуки.

Comment: Посмотрел на код - ужаснулся, прогнал через автоиндент - ужаснулся второй раз :) В оригинале, скорее всего, было скопировано с pdf-ки.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в строчках

```
const int N = 1;
int A[N]={0};
```

Массив всегда размера 1.